# Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range), Target always equals Nothing

Tags: excel, vba

thanks for all your help in advance!
I am using the `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` event **NOT** the `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` event. After some testing I realized that my event fires but the argument `Target` is always set to  `Nothing`.  Some code and a picture fallows.

```
Private pNet As Range
Private pProposedValue As Range

'EVENT HANDLERS
'--------------
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If pProposedValue Is Nothing Then

    ElseIf pNet Is Nothing Then

    ElseIf Target Is pNet Then
        pProposedValue.Value2 = Target.Value2
        Me.Calculate
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Set the breakpoint on `If pProposedValue Is Nothing Then` instead and then hover over `Target` to check its value. Or make the first line of the `Sub` something like `Debug.Print (Target Is Nothing)`.

Comment: Do you have any volatile functions on the sheet?

Comment: `Is` doesn't work for checking if one range variable refers to the same range as another range variable. `Target Is pNet` will be false even if they refer to the same range.

Comment: Hit F8 to execute at least the function header before checking to see if target is Nothing

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your info, I thought that is one way to test object reference equality? I thought that since Range returns a range object that I would be able to test the reference.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie after fallowing your advice it seems as though Target is still Nothing according to intellesense even at the end of the sub

Comment: @Comintern that is very possible but I dont think so. The only knew functions I have written sense the bug have been the two inside the picture. I had a previous version of this program working fine and the end user wanted me to add in this extra bit.

Comment: @TimWilliams[SOLVED] I used your comment and changed the `Is` to a `Taget.address = pNet.address` and the whole thing works as expected now. strange but I cant complain! is there a way for me to mark your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is` doesn't work for checking if one range variable refers to the same range as another range variable.

`Target Is pNet` will be false even if they refer to the same range.

Comment: While this [ultimately solves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) the OP's problem, the question title and body are asking for a different answer, which is ["step into the procedure before hovering over `Target`"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111907/worksheet-changebyval-target-as-range-target-always-equals-nothing#comment65571849_39111907).